# Where are Full Bleed Layer image icons used?

Tags: android

My question is:
When creating an app icon, something called `Full Bleed Layers` is created as well and I don't know where this icon will be in use.

[image: Icons]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Full [bleed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleed_(printing)) layers = the base adaptive icon, which is being masked (it is only being shown masked).

The link in the SDK documentation is broken: see [Designing Adaptive Icons](https://medium.com/google-design/designing-adaptive-icons-515af294c783).